# How do I configure my api node to receive ISO-8859-1

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, iso-8859-1, charset

Today I have a Node.js server that has an API service for customers.
An example would be receiving a CRM webhook.

```
router.route('/webhook/service/notifications/crm/syonet/convert')
.post(convertSyonet)

module.exports = router
```

Where a CRM sends the following header in the request:

Content-Type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1

And with that my server returns the following error:

```
<h1>unsupported charset &quot;ISO-8859-1&quot;</h1>
<h2>415</h2>
<pre>UnsupportedMediaTypeError: unsupported charset &quot;ISO-8859-1&quot;
    at jsonParser
```

How do I accept the request for this crm?

Comment: Oh god. Why are people still using ISO-8859? We've have UTF-8 since 1993!

Comment: @Quentin wikipedia says second most used char coding after UTF with 3.5%

Comment: Please show us your express configuration, specifically the json parser.

Comment: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/body-parser.html#unsupported-charset-bogus